# change font family with cluture

Tags: c#, wpf, cultureinfo

In app.xaml.cs I do the following to change the main control font size, and family

```
public App()
{
    Style style = new Style
    {
        TargetType = typeof(Window)
    };

    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Window.FontFamilyProperty, new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("Consolas")));
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Window.FontSizeProperty,  30.0));

    FrameworkElement.StyleProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Window), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
    {
        DefaultValue = style
    });
}
```

and on the button to change the culture

```
 private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (x)
            {
                var selectrCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("Ar-EG");

                CultureResources.ChangeCulture(selectrCultureInfo);
                FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
                x = false;
                EventUserControl.LanguageFlag = false;

                Style style = new Style
                {
                    TargetType = typeof(Window)
                };

                style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Window.FontFamilyProperty, new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("Traditional Arabic")));
                style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Window.FontSizeProperty, 140.0));

                FrameworkElement.StyleProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Window), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
                {
                    DefaultValue = style
                });
            }
            else
            {
                var selectrCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("EN-US");

                CultureResources.ChangeCulture(selectrCultureInfo);
                FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
                x = true;
                EventUserControl.LanguageFlag = true;
                Style style = new Style
                {
                    TargetType = typeof(Window)
                };

                style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Window.FontFamilyProperty, new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("Consolas")));
                style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Window.FontSizeProperty, 30.0));

                FrameworkElement.StyleProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Window), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
                {
                    DefaultValue = style
                });
            }
        }
```

but i get error PropertyMetadata is already registered for type 'Window'. any idea to solve this or unregister and reregister the metadata

Comment: From the Remarks section on the [DependencyProperty.OverrideMetadata](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597491(v=vs.110).aspx) page: *Calls to OverrideMetadata should only be performed within the static constructors of the type that provides itself as the* forType *parameter of this method, or through similar instantiation. Attempting to change metadata after instances of the owner type exist will not raise exceptions, but will result in inconsistent behaviors in the property system*...

Comment: ... *After metadata for a particular derived class override is established with this method, subsequent attempts to override metadata on this same derived class will raise an exception.* So you are not supposed to call it anywhere during runtime, especially not repeatedly for the same type.

Comment: @Clemens so how to reach my goal please